# one dimensional poincare inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

> Given $\Omega=[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ and the Sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$
>
> Let $v \in H_0^1(\Omega) $ prove the following inequality
> $$\Vert v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}\le\frac{\Vert \dot v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}}{\sqrt2}(b-a)$$

My thoughts/ideas: I looked at the case that $\ v(x)=\int_a^x \dot v(t)dt$
By Schwarz inequality I get the following: $v(x)^2\le (x-a)\Vert \dot v \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$

If I integrate both sides and take the square root I get exactly what I wanted to show. However, $\ v(x)=\int_a^b \dot v(t)dt$ isn't necessarily true

I would appreciate any help because I am stuck. I am not too familiar with Sobolev spaces because I couldn't really understand the definition.

Comment: It is just an instance of Wirtinger's inequality (second version): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions

Answer (score 1):

$\int_a^b \dot{v}  (t) \, dt $ is not a function of $x$, so your identity is in fact never true (well, almost never). Did you intend to write $\int_a^x$?

Try to prove the inequality for smooth functions. If you can do that show it's stable under approximation in the space $H^1_0$ to prove it in the general case (this assumes you know that smooth functions are dense in that space).

Comment: Since smooth functions are dense in $H$ , does it follow that there exit a sequence of $v_n$ such that $v_n\ \rightarrow v$ ?

Comment: @XPenguen Yes, with smooth $v_n$, and "$\rightarrow$" refers to the $H^1$ norm.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to prove this for smoth functions ?

Comment: @XPenguen have a look at your own question, and replace $\int_a^b$ with $\int_a^x$ where appropriate.

Comment: But I would need $v(a)=0$ . Otherwise I couldnt write $v(x)=\int_a^x \dot v(t)dt$ ? Or is that true if $v \in H^1$ ?

Comment: @XPenguen you are working in $H^1_0$, aren't you? Note the lower index $0$. How did you define this?